# the skull protects "on the brain" or "the brain"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

What's correct?

> 1) The skull protects **on** the brain

or

> 2) the skull protects *the brain*

Comment: What does your dictionary say about the verb "protect"?  Is it transitive or intransitive?

Comment: I'm happy that I learnt new term in English "transitive" and in "transitive", and I know their meaning in my language, but actually this is the first time that I'm exposed to these terms in English. I don't have idea and I've never noticed if any dictionary refers to this point. Indeed, after looking at the relevant entry I can say that you thought me a big lesson in grammar. Of course, in this case the answer is "protect on" because it's transitive verb. Thank you so much. 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protect

Comment: 8-O the answer is "protect on"?  How did you get that from that page in  Merriam-Webster's?  There is no such sequence of words anywhere on that page!

Comment: And apparently you didn't get what "transitive" and "intransitive" mean... I say, read about those again.

Comment: You're right I opposite it inadvertently. I think that now it's Ok. Am I right? Look at my answer please.

Comment: Yet, *the skull protects on the brain* is not an impossible clause or sentence. Almost every sentence and usage depends on context. Which is why, without a context, I can't answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:
it depends on the context, because according to the context it's decided if it's transitive or intransitive verbs.

In this context is a transitive verb and therefore the answer is "protects" (without prepositional)

> The skull **protects** the brain

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protect

Comment: Kudos!  Better late than never.

Comment: Indeed. :D sometimes when I focus on one thing I can miss the others. But I'm working on focusing all the planes.